# Filtering the result based on max date using Hazelcast jet

Tags: java, hazelcast

How to filter the `BatchStage` result based on max date.

Here is my code..

```
    BatchStage<TestModel> testModel = value.map(model -> JsonUtil.mapFrom(model.getObject_value()))
                .map(json -> new TestModel(json.get("id"), json.get("json_obs")));
```

Here is the model class

```
public class TestModel implements Serializable {

    private Object key;
    private Object value;
    //getters and setter
    // HashCode and equals method
}
```

In the console I'm currently getting this output

```
TestModel [key=0001, value=[{date=09/03/2021}, {date=10/03/2021}]]
TestModel[key=0002,  value=[{date=09/03/2021}, {date=11/03/2021}]]
```

Now I wants to keep only the max date map in the value object

example:-

```
TestModel [key=0001, value=[{date=10/03/2021}]]
TestModel[key=0002,  value=[{date=11/03/2021}]]
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I'd suggest you to choose between mapping exactly the model or using JSON. Using a model that has 2 attributes of type `Object` is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to write a function, which need to get the max date in a list of date.

And I think i need to know the type of "date"...
if it is the type of "java.util.Date", the function can be like this:

```
public static Date getMaxDate(List<Date> dates) {
    if (dates.size() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No date value in list...");
    }
    Date max = dates.get(0);
    for (Date date : dates) {
        //use the implemented compareTo() function
        if (max.compareTo(date) < 0) {
            max = date;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

if it is a type of "java.time.LocalDate" the function can be like this:

```
public static LocalDate getMaxLocalDate(List<LocalDate> dates) {
    if (dates.size() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No date value in list...");
    }
    LocalDate max = dates.get(0);
    for (LocalDate date : dates) {
        //use isBefore function
        if (max.isBefore(date)) {
            max = date;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

and if it is your own type, defined like:

```
public class MyDate {
    public int year;
    public int month;
    public int day;

    public MyDate() {
    }

    public MyDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyDate{" +
                "year=" + year +
                ", month=" + month +
                ", day=" + day +
                '}';
    }
}
```

then the function can be like this:

```
public static MyDate getMaxMyDate(List<MyDate> dates) {
    if (dates.size() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No date value in list...");
    }
    MyDate max = dates.get(0);
    LocalDate maxLocalDate = LocalDate.of(max.year, max.month, max.day);
    for (MyDate date : dates) {
        //convert to LocalDate to compare
        LocalDate currentLocalDate = LocalDate.of(date.year, date.month, date.day);
        if (maxLocalDate.isBefore(currentLocalDate)) {
            max = date;
            maxLocalDate = LocalDate.of(max.year, max.month, max.day);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

and it seems that you need to get a result as list, you can use `List.of(max)` to get a list result.